# Can't find xpath on second loop / pass

Tags: javascript, python, selenium

I am a newbie and hobby programmer and have reached a dead end on this one.  I am trying to loop through a website and grab & print data.  Whilst the code works for the 1st one, I cannot get it to "click" the second item on the "original" list of links.  My code is as follows:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

#set chromepath to include .exe
chrome_path = r"C:\Program Files\Python37\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)

#set variables
myurl='http://www.ctbar.org/search/newsearch.asp'
loop_results = 1
pagination = 1
next_section = 1
counter = 0

driver.get(myurl) # loads the 1st page into the browser

driver.switch_to_frame('SearchResultsFrame')#switches focus to the results frame
id_results1 = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,('//*[contains(@id,"MiniProfileLink")]'))# put results into an array

while counter <= len(id_results1)-1: # for testing only print / see all the list
    text_results1 = id_results1[(counter)].text
    print (text_results1)
    counter +=1

id_results1[0].click() # click the first entry
#grab the email address and print it
email = driver.find_element_by_xpath ('//*[@id="SpContent_Container"]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[3]/table[1]/tbody/tr/td/a').text
print (email)
driver.back()      
print ('second click')
driver.switch_to_frame('SearchResultsFrame')#switches focus to the results frame
id_results2 = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,('//*[contains(@id,"MiniProfileLink")]')) # re-grab the results
#for testing, put the results into a variable & print
text_results2 = id_results2[2].text 
print (text_results2) 

print('Done')
driver.quit()
```

I have tried numerous ways to get the second click to work from the first list and don't know where to go next.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't see your `second click` attempt anyway. I only see `print ('second click')` just after `driver.back()` Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to click but got nothing. I decided to see if I could see / print the link first and then convert to clicking it. Can’t see it, so I thought I can’t click it either.

Answer (score 0):

I would say its easier to do this in two steps:

1) gather all primary links (i.e. to the people) with pagination as they look like static urls from the IDs

2) Gather the emails in a second loop.

This avoids the back and forth which may be error prone and subject to load times.

To avoid load time hang:

```
driver.set_page_load_timeout(30)# 30 second time limit.
```

Comment: Ok. Not sure how I’d do that?